# Is it possible to add a method dynamically in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

Hey I am making a firebase database call that looks like this:

```
db.collection("posts").where("location", "==", location)
    .get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        [...]
    })
```

The user can specify from what countries he would like to get posts (the `.where()` method is for that). But he can also pick all the countries, so in that case the method is no longer needed. Is there a way to add methods dynamically?

Something like this:

```
db.collection("posts")if(location != "all"){.where("location", "==", location)}
    .get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        [...]
    })
```

Comment: Just put the function call inside a condition: `let query = db.collection(...); if (...) query = query.where(...); query.get().then(...)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a function

```
const addLocationCondition = (collection, location) => 
    location === "all" ? collection : collection.where('location', '==', location);

addLocationCondition(db.collection('posts'), location).get()...
```

Comment: A shorter alternative than an `if` statement, as well as a cleaner alternative to the other answers. I like it!

Comment: @Reality "Make const not var". :) It will look even better if/when this proposal got adopted https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pipeline-operator `db.collection('post') |> addLocationCondition(#, location) |> #.get() |> await`

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't put a conditional there.

Just use `if` to decide whether to call `.where()`.

```
let posts = db.collection("posts");
let filtered;
if (location == "all") {
    filtered = posts;
} else {
    filtered = posts.where("location", "==", location);
}
filtered.get().then(querySnapshot => { 
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure about this `db` API but this should work:

```
let query = db.collection("posts")
if(location != "all"){
  query = query.where("location", "==", location)
}
query.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
   [...]
})
```